# How to do left joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to do this simple sql query to LINQ. But its give me error.

Here is the SQL query that need to conver to LINQ

```
 DECLARE @groupID int
 SET @groupID = 2
 SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Person p
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonGroup pg ON ( p.PersonID = pg.PersonID AND pg.GroupID = @groupID)
```

Ignore @groupID. which will be provided as function parameter for LINQ query.

Here is LINQ query what i have tried.

```
from p in Person
 join pg in PersonGroup on new { p.PersonID, groupID } equals new { pg.PersonID, pg.GroupID } into t
 from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Where groupID is provided as function parameter. Both GroupID and PersonID are int. But it gives me following error,

```
Error   2   The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.
```

Little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Code

```
from p in Person
 join pg in PersonGroup on new { p.PersonID, groupID } equals new { pg.PersonID, pg.GroupID } into t
 from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Change it to

```
from p in Person
 join pg in PersonGroup on new { Person = p.PersonID, Group = groupID } equals new { Person = pg.PersonID, Group = pg.GroupID } into t
 from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

That way it will join using the Anonymous type